# Repair partition table metadata

Tags: windows-10, partition-recovery

I have a GPT-formatted hard drive that I messed up by deleting and re-creating 1 empty partition for a live windows 7 usb, formatted with Rufus. My installed OS now gives unmountable_boot_volume and I suspect the partition table was damaged. Lubuntu's Disks tool says I have 1 bad sector, so I think it might be related to that. (I don't suspect hardware failure here; it's new and the timing is too perfect for coincidence.)

Windows 10 and bios system recovery aren't working (black screen, no response). I'd like to repair the partition table metadata with a live lubuntu OS. What can I do?

Comment: The best course of action is to provide us the exact error message you received.

Comment: You wanted to know the best action to take.  Unless we know the reason Windows 7 will not install, we cannot tell you, how to install it.

Comment: Please adjust the title then to summarize your question, and possibly remove anything that is no longer relevant? (I did not read your question.)

Comment: So you want to know how to format the drive or recover the data?

Comment: @Ramhound If possible, I'd like to format the drive. I have already recovered all useful data, but preferably, I'd like to keep the OS as well. If this isn't possible, I will still take your advice. Thanks.

Comment: Boot to the Live Environment of the Linux distribution of your choice, load up Gparted, format your system drive.

Comment: @Ramhound alright, I've updated with some more information. I don't want to just google formatting the system drive; I'm really looking for some more pointed advice (like specific to the partitioning on the drive). If I have to format the whole sshd, I'd like specific commands to run. Too risky that I'd incorrectly format trying to understand the commands on my own